# The perfect callback function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, function-pointers, perfect-forwarding

Goal : Obtain a callback function that will take any type of parameters as the callback function's parameters

```
.h
template <typename F, typename A>
void DelayedCallback(F&& CallbackFunction, A&& Args = NULL);
```

/

```
.cpp
void DelayedCallback(F&& CallbackFunction, A&& Args)
{
  //Timer function that received a function pointer to be the "callback"  function
  Timer((std::bind(std::forward<F>(CallbackFunction), std::forward<A>(Args)))())
}
```

/

```
DelayedCallback(&HUDExit);

void HUDExit() {}
```

/

```
ERROR : DelayedCallback(FName,float,F &&,A &&)' : could not deduce template argument for 'A'
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm new to most of these concept in c++, more of c# programmer

EDIT : It's not only about the error, I'm pretty sure it's not the only one I am making.

Comment: 1. Don't implement template functions in separate translation units. 2. Don't miss the `template` prefixes with their implementation.

Comment: Everything should therefore be in the .h .  What do you mean by don't miss the template prefixes with their implementation?

Comment: _"What do you mean by don't miss the template prefixes ..."_ `template <typename F, typename A> void DelayedCallback(F&& CallbackFunction, A&& Args) { /* ... */ }` i mean for the definition.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Somehow I doubt *could not deduce template argument for 'A'* is being caused because the OP placed the implementation in a cpp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message doesn't match the signature of `DelayedCallback`

```
template <typename F, typename A>
void DelayedCallback(F&& CallbackFunction, A&& Args = NULL)

DelayedCallback(&HUDExit);
```

That function signature and the usage you've shown will not produce an error message that says

> ERROR : `DelayedCallback(FName,float,F &&,A &&)`' : could not deduce template argument for 'A'

But ignoring the template parameter mismatches, the code you've shown will also result in a similar error. The problem is that template parameters cannot be deduced from default arguments and `A` is treated as a non-deduced context in your example.

From N3337, *§14.8.2.5/5 [temp.deduct.type]*

> The non-deduced contexts are: 
>   ...
>   — A template parameter used in the parameter type of a function parameter that has a default argument that is being used in the call for which argument deduction is being done.

Instead, you should change `A` to a parameter pack. That'll allow you to pass zero or more arguments to `DelayedCallback`.

```
template <typename F, typename... A>
void DelayedCallback(F&& CallbackFunction, A&&... Args)
{
  //Timer function that received a function pointer to be the "callback"  function
  Timer((std::bind(std::forward<F>(CallbackFunction), std::forward<A>(Args)...))())
  // previous line is missing a semicolon at the very least
}
```

---

Once you fix all that, you'll run into the problem mentioned in the comments. You [cannot split](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/241631) the declaration and definition of a function template between a header and source file as you would with a non-template. So implement `DelayedCallback` in the header itself as I have done above.

Comment: Sorry I cut 2 extra parameters that were worthless to the question :S

Is there a solution of not using header file? I'm in Unreal SDK (3) and I'm not sure what are the limitations toward this type of usage?

Comment: @Fawar No, there aren't any alternatives that are useful in general. It's highly unlikely you'll run into problems implementing a function template in a header, Unreal SDK or otherwise.

Comment: I'll try this and see if I get anything out of it, thank you very much for your help! If what you wrote happens to help me out or make it work I will accept your answer and post the result of what I built around this